# Need a persistent place to store a backup of my Core Data store

Tags: ios, core-data, ios8.1, nsdocumentdirectory

I have an app that creates a backup of my Core Data store and stores it in the NSDocuments directory.  When I try to restore from that directory (*without restarting the app*), everything is restored correctly.  However, *if I stop the app*, restart it and try to do a restore, the directory is different and the restore uses an old version of the backup file (haven't a clue where it came from).

My question is:  because I need to persist the latest backup file, where can I save it so it will be there when I need it?  (possibly after many distinct executions of my app).  I don't want to use iTunes, so I was thinking of possibly iCloud; I need something that is not accessable to the user so he/she can't accidently delete the backup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Library/ApplicationSupport will do what I need... (just in case someone else needs the same info).  SD